# Is there any program library support filtering JSON like mongodb query syntax?

Tags: json, mongodb

In mongodb, I can use query JSON like {"size":40} to get documents which size is 40.

Is there any program library to filter/check pure JSON document with a JSON query statement?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com), or [underscore](http://underscorejs.org).

A function like [filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) would be a good example.

Something like this can be used:

```
var items = [{
  "id": 1,
  "size": 3
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "size": 4
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "size": 1
}];


var result = items.filter(function(item) {
  return item.size == 1;
});

console.log(result);
```

[Good video describing the use of the `filter()` function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMUiFMZr7vk)